# VBscript subroutines and functions

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make my first vbscript, but it is a bit complicated.  I know some VBA but totally new to vb.  In my script, I currently have some sub () and function () routines.  How would I get the script to start, so the main sub () can run and make the necessary calls?

If you could advise or point me to a site that may be better suited to novice queries, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the context in which you're using vbscript. I'll assume you're using it for scripting with the WSH.

If you had the main logic in a sub called `mysub()`, you'd normally just place a call to it at the top of your script:

```
mysub

Sub mysub ()
...
End Sub
```

And of course, you have to run the script. From memory, I think that would be `cscript myscript.vbs` from the command prompt.

To learn more about VBScript, have a look at MS TechNet's [Sesame Script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd772284.aspx) series of tutorials. There's one specifically on functions and subroutines [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176984.aspx). To get help, you could try the TechNet [forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home).

Comment: Thanks for that - sorted me out.  Took a little while to test, but I think all is well.  Many thanks!